# how to use Gstreamer for rtsp proxy

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, video-processing, gstreamer

I want to create an rtsp proxy where rtsp stream can be taken from one end and then need to stream the same(using rtsp) on other side.This is more of a rtsp relay but I wanted to trans code this relayed stream in between.

Can anyone suggest a way for doing this? I had considered Gstreamer for this, but that can act only as rtsp server, but I still don't know how to get the rtsp stream from other side and how to relay rtsp events.

Any existing library which can help me in achieving this? or If Gstreamer can be used in this way ?

Answer (score 1):

Gstreamer should be able to use RTSP on input, there is [rtspsrc](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-rtspsrc.html) element for it.